# In C#, if I call a method from a different class which is not instantiated, is that class instantiated when the method is called?

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management

```
class State
{
    public void FalconPunch()
    {
        Console.Writeline("Punched.")
    }
}

class Testy
{
    public void TryThis()
    {
        State.FalconPunch();
    }
}
```

When the method TryThis() in class Testy calls State.FalconPunch(), is class State instantiated (even for a moment) in order to execute the FalconPunch() method?

I'm trying to decide whether static states are necessary, for all the AI agents in my game to use. It's on the mobile platform so I am trying to write with optimization in mind.

Comment: That won't compile in the first place. (Sorry, Captain Falcon...)

Comment: Why didn't you try first? As mentioned by a lot of people, this code won't even compile. You could at least have tried that before posting your question.

Comment: I did try it, it's just my mistake -- In the engine I'm using, the way the class is called on the GameObject, it is already considered an instance, so it works without being static.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't call `FalconPunch` without a reference to an instance since it is not `static`.

You must create a new instance, manually, before.

Short:
`new State().FalconPunch()`

Complete:
`var s = new State(); s.FalconPunch();`

Comment: Of course, you could always make the method `static`, in which case you would *not* have to create an instance of the class first. That's probably what the asker is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

FalconPunch is not a static method, so this will not compile. You have to specifically create an instance in order to call the method.